# Query whole database but only print the first row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to query the whole table from the database ive created but only print Title and Summary from the first row, I havent been able to find a way to do this, heres the code i have so far:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root'); 
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test.articles ORDER BY Date") or die('Unable to run query:' . mysqli_error($con));     
?>

<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo  "<h1>" . $row['Title'] . "</h1>";
        echo  "<p>" . $row['Summary'] . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

I've tried using `mysqli_fetch_row`, along with other ways but havent been able to find the solution, thanks.

Comment: don't use the while loop in you code ... you will get only the first row ...

Comment: `LIMI 1` is the best solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `while` to `if`

This will print only first row...

***BUT this is not right way.***

Right way would be LIMIT the data

```
SELECT * FROM test.articles ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1
                                          ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: when i change it to if, it displays nothing? i think the if solution suits my problem better?

Comment: @Ben : **NO**... you should use `LIMIT 1`. Think you have lakhs of data and you need only top row... To read top row are you gonna read lakhs of data? ***Obviously NO***

Answer (score 1):

Just call `mysqli_fetch_array()` once (remove your loop):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo  "<h1>" . $row['Title'] . "</h1>";
echo  "<p>" . $row['Summary'] . "</p>";
```

And if you really only want one row, use a `LIMIT` clause to limit your results to one row. It will be more performant:

```
SELECT * FROM test.articles ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1
```